# Division to the nearest 1 decimal place without floating point math?

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer, division

I am having some speed issues with my C# program and identified that this percentage calculation is causing a slow down.  The calculation is simply n/d * 100.  Both the numerator and denominator can be any integer number. The numerator can never be greater than the denominator and is never negative.  Therefore, the result is always from 0-100.  Right now, this is done by simply using floating point math and is somewhat slow, since it's being calculated tens of millions of times.  I really don't need anything more accurate than to the nearest 0.1 percent.  And, I just use this calculated value to see if it's bigger than a fixed constant value. I am thinking that everything should be kept as an integer, so the range with 0.1 accuracy would be 0-1000.  Is there some way to calculate this percentage without floating point math?

Here is the loop that I am using with calculation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < simulationList.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < simulationList.Count; j++)
    {
        int matches = GetMatchCount(simulationList[i], simulationList[j]);
        if ((float)matches / (float)simulationList[j].Catchments.Count > thresPercent)
        {
            simulationList[j].IsOverThreshold = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it's a fairly sparse/tight loop where that might cause such a bottleneck. Can we see it?

Comment: I would guess that if this is really what's slowing down your program, cache effects will likely be playing just as big a role as the difference between integer and floating-point maths. Additionally boxing/unboxing or anything else that might cause allocation I would expect to have a bigger effect than the maths operations.

Comment: I just added the loop that I am using to the message.

Comment: I think most of the time is spent converting your variables to float, and not in the division.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `n/d > c`, you can use `n > d * c` (supposing that `d > 0`).
(`c` is the constant value you are comparing to.)

This way you don't need division at all.

However, watch out for the overflows.

Comment: This is good, since it even gets rid of division completely, which is usually more expensive than multiplication.

Comment: Nowadays, division and multiplication cost the same on modenr CPUs.

Comment: @Loadmaster: isn't integer multiplication cheaper than conversion from ints to floats and floating point division?

Comment: @Loadmaster: Seems I'm a bit out of date then, since I always thought integer multiplication was less expensive than integer division. @Vlad: It is, however you can do it with integer division too by doing (1000 * n) / d

Comment: @Matti: optimizing compilers replace integer division by a constant with integer multiplication and a bit shift, hence no difference in cost.  I'm pretty sure division by a variable is still several times slower than multiplication.

Comment: @Matti, @Loadmaster: at least this article suggests that the integer division is still considerably slower than multiplication: http://www.xzing.org/?itemid=339

Comment: And this processor timing table suggests that the integer is slower at modern processors: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: (in my previous comment, read "integer" as "integer division")

Comment: @DavidRTribble  That's not true.  Integer multiplication is done in one clock cycle, on almost all 21st century chips.  But most processors - including the latest x86 - can take anywhere from 9 to 40 cycles for an integer division.

Answer (score 0):

If your units are in tenths instead of ones, then you can get your 0.1 accuracy using integer arithmetic:

Instead of:

```
for (...)
{
    float n = ...;
    float d = ...;

    if (n / d > 1.4) // greater than 140% ?
```

...do something like:

```
for (...)
{
    int n = 10 * ...;
    int d = ...;
    if (n / d > 14) // greater than 140% ?
```

Comment: For speed, use `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
if ((float)matches / (float)simulationList[j].Catchments.Count > thresPercent)
```

write this:

```
if (matches * theresPercent_Denominator > simulationList[j].Catchments.Count * thresPercent_Numerator)
```

In this way, you get rid of the floating points.

Note: `thresPercent` can be expressed as `thresPercent_Numerator / theresPercent_Denominator`, as long as the number is a rational number.)  I think this is the optimal way on PC.  For some other platform, you may further optimize it by left-shift or right-shift, if theresPercent_Denominator and/or thresPercent_Numerator are 2's power. (Normally left-shift is enough, but may need use right-shift by rearrange the equation to division, to prevent from overflow)